# Rails sorting by popularity score

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display items by an external popularity score that gets generated by looking at the number of "likes" the item has.

**item.rb**

```
belongs_to :restaurant
has_many :liked_items
has_many :items, through: :liked_items
```

**likeditem.rb**

```
belongs_to :item
```

**controller.rb**

```
@popular = Hash.new(0)
      @importitems = @restaurant.items
      @importitems.each do |i|
        @likecount = i.liked_items.count
        @popular[i] += @likecount
      end
      @items = @popular.sort_by { |key, value| value }.reverse
```

However, I need `@items` to ONLY contain the items, not the item + score in an array. Is there a more efficient way to sort by popular then only return the items?

Comment: Is there a better way than using a bunch of N+1 loops and iterations? Certainly the answer is "Yes". Perhaps considering using a query instead...

Comment: Do you mean query for the liked_items that contain a set of item_ids? How would I do that?

Comment: Looks like you got it. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up turning this into a query:

```
@items = @importitems.left_joins(:liked_items)
                          .group(:id)
                          .order('COUNT(liked_items.id) DESC')
                          .limit(10)
```